# Sequence of CoreData inserting in iphone is not as I am inserting

Tags: ios, core-data

I am inserting some objects in coredata, but when I do retrieve them, their sequence is not same as I inserted, even index is properly managed,

```
-(void)addQuestion
 {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[array addObject:@"What is capital of Australia?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of Canada?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of UAE?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of USA?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of Pakistan?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of China?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of UK?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of Russia?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of Romania?"];
[array addObject:@"What is capital of Germany?"];


for (int x = 0; x<10; x++) {

    Question *question = [NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Question"
                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
    question.question =  [array objectAtIndex:x];
    question.answer = @"Testville";
    question.mcqsa = @"Sydney";
    question.mcqsb = @"Canbera";
    question.mcqsc =  @"Berlin";
    question.mcqsd = @"Bern";

}



NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

// Test listing all FailedBankInfos from the store
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Question"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (Question *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", info.question);
}

}
```

LOg Displays

```
2013-06-04 17:59:59.978 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of Romania?
2013-06-04 17:59:59.979 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of Australia?
2013-06-04 17:59:59.979 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of Pakistan?  
2013-06-04 17:59:59.980 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of Russia? 
2013-06-04 17:59:59.980 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of USA?
2013-06-04 17:59:59.981 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of UK?
2013-06-04 17:59:59.981 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of UAE?
2013-06-04 17:59:59.982 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of Germany?
2013-06-04 17:59:59.982 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of China?
2013-06-04 17:59:59.982 iQuiz[972:c07] Name: What is capital of Canada?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707905/retrieve-core-data-entities-in-order-of-insertion

Answer (score 3):

That's normal behavior. Insertion order (or any order for that matter) is not guaranteed. If the order is important, add an extra attribute `index` that you increment and can sort on when fetching objects.

Comment: Integer 16, 32, or 64, which should i use?

Comment: That depends a little on how many records you expect to have. Integer 16 gives you 65535 maximum records, Integer 32 4294967295, and Integer 64 18446744073709600000. I'd say probably 32.

Comment: and there is also an error when I add NSInteger to object, that Property with strong and retain attribute must be of object type. It comes when I write code in Question.h

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger *index;

Comment: Don't write that. Let Xcode generate the `NSManagedObject` subclasses for you.

Comment: But I have generated before, and then updated attribute, so now

Comment: Thanks I regenerated new file.

Comment: Adding a date attribute is an easy way to achieve indexing. Sort by that timestamp with your NSPredicate rather than creating your own increment int.

Comment: @DCGoD: True, but only if you never plan on changing the order.

Comment: @Scott I completely agree but "if" that's the case it's just another variable that should be added to the question. He mentions only returning results as they were inserted so this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to have a relationship rather than an attribute. Then set the relationship to ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its normal. Totally. Just track id yourself and use NSSortDescriptor to sort on it while quering. That is the recommended approach.